# how can i split up a large django-celery tasks.py module into smaller chunks?

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I have some very lengthy task functions that I would like to break out from my `tasks.py` module, but still be able to call like `from myapp.tasks import my_task`.  I tried creating submodules for each task, but then I have to insert some trickery into `tasks/__init__.py`, which seems pretty hackish (and requires giving the tasks the same names as the modules):

```
import pkgutil

for module_loader, name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(__path__):
    __import__('myapp.tasks.%s' % name)
    locals().update({name: getattr(locals()[name], name)})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This answer is about management commands rather than tasks in the sense of Celery background tasks.*

---

I think the most straight-forward solution is to first write the tasks as Django management commands, and then call those from tasks.py.  This way you can break up your tasks into one task per file, and have the additional benefit of being able to call your tasks arbitrarily from the command line.

So, in `tasks.py`:

```
from django.core import management

@task()
def my_task():
    management.call_command('my_task')
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works as well:

- create a package `tasks`
- spread your tasks in python modules inside the `tasks` package
- import the modules in the `tasks/__init__.py`

Example:

```
django_app
| tasks
   | __init__.py
   | filesystem_tasks.py
| admin.py
| url.py
```

- `tasks/filesystem_tasks.py` can contain this:

  ```
  from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
  from celery import shared_task

  @shared_task
  def add(x, y):
      return x + y
  ```
- `tasks/__init__.py` can contain this:

  ```
  from .filesystem_tasks import *
  ```
- Running celery indicates the tasks as they would have been declared in one `tasks.py` at the same level as eg. `url.py`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Django-Celery but quite familiar with Celery, so this is more of a general note which may answer your question...

Celery tasks are identified by name when executed.  By default, tasks are given the name of their Python location, ie. `'%s.%s' % (my_task.__module__, my_task.__name__)`, or 'myapp.tasks.function_name'.  That said, you can override the task name by supplying the @task decorator with the 'name' kwarg.  So if you wanted to override a task name:

```
# We're in myapp.tasks but the task will not be named myapp.tasks.my_task as expected
@task(name='some.overridden.name')
def my_task():
    print 'Something'
```

Comment: But how does that help break up your code into separate files?  My problem is the size of myapp.tasks is getting unwieldy.

Comment: Well, this allows you to name tasks what you want in their own module and then import those tasks into tasks.py but call them by the names you assigned to them.  Note that there may be a better way of doing this in Django-celery, I'm not familiar with the restrictions it applies.  For instance, if this were standard Celery, you would simply add all the modules you have tasks in to the CELERY_IMPORTS directive in your Celery configuration file and Celery would import them and make them available to invoke.

Comment: I see, Loren, thanks.  I'll give this a try, in conjunction with my own idea for a better solution (using Django management commands).